# Concatenate vector size to string

Tags: c++, string, vector

I'm trying to concatenate a string with a vector size. Whatever method I use, I don't get the desired output. When I use `cout` it prints fine and when I look at the value of the string in my debugger, it appears as `Schemes(\002)`. Problem is: I need to return a string, rather than print straight to the console, so I can't use `cout`; I must use concatenation. Why is the string and the vector size not concatenating as expected?

**Desired string:** schemes(2)

**Outputted string:** schemes()

**Code:**

```
using namespace std;    

string s;
vector<Object> schemes;

// Add two elements to vector

// Method 1 (doesn't work)
s += "Schemes(" + schemes.size();
s += ")"; // I can't put this on the same line because I get 'expression must have integral or unscoped enum type' error

// Method 2 (doesn't work)
s += "Schemes(";
s.push_back(schemes.size());
s += ")";

// Method 3 (doesn't work)
s += "Schemes(";
s.append(schemes.size());
s += ")";
```

Comment: "*I need to return a string, rather than print straight to the console, so I can't use cout; I must use concatenation*" - actually, you don't. You can use a `std::ostringstream` so you can utilize the same `operator<<` operations you use with `std::cout`, just the output goes to a `std::string` instead: `ostringstream oss; oss << "Schemes(" << schemes.size() << ")"; s = oss.str();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

schemes.size() is an integer type. This means you're trying to concatenate an integer type to a string type.

Try

```
s = "Schemes(" + to_string(schemes.size()) + ")";
```